# winter bash hat?

Tags: discussion, meta, winter-bash

I am new to this meta StackExchange community, So I do not have much knowledge about Winter Bash and earning hat meaning in my profile.

Is is just of fun or really mean something.

Comment: It's serious business!!... Nah, just a bit of annual fun. :)

Answer (score 3):

Winter Bash is a fun event that happens at the end of every year. For a few weeks, as you use the site, you'll earn "hats" that you can put on your avatar. There's a list of hats and a leaderboard at https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com.

It's all for fun - there's no obligation to participate or anything, and the hats will all disappear after a few weeks. If you don't want to see any of these hat things, feel free to click "I hate hats" in the snowflake dropdown.